# how to set mogodb in upstart service with authentication in mongodb way

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, startup

I set username and password in MongoDB every time I have to run this command in terminal:

```
sudo mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

As soon as I close terminal, MongoDB db also closes so how will I set MongoDB in startup service?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sudo service` to start MongoDB as a service, check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) for further details:

```
sudo service mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

How to install on Ubuntu is handled extremely well in the [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) so I won't rehash that here (plus it is updated more frequently than this answer will be).

Once you have installed MongoDB using that guide you can then modify the config file at `/etc/mongod.conf` to reflect your desired config (auth etc.).  Finally, you then start/stop the database with `sudo service mongod start` and `sudo service mongod stop`.